# Display comments on post yii

Tags: yii

I only want display comments belonging to each post ,

I have done this :
 In Post `view.php` I have render a view :

```
<?php 

 $this->renderPartial('/TblComments/_comment',array(

     'comments'=>$model_comments,
        ));
```

?>

here is `_comment.php`

```
<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('user_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->user_id); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('post_id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->post_id); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('comment_body')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->comment_body); ?>
    <br />


        <?php echo CHtml::link('Edit', array('tblComments/update', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
        <br/>
        <?php echo CHtml::link('Delete', array('tblComments/delete', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>

</div>
```

Now problem is :

```
Undefined variable: data
```

I donot know why ? Please explain and help me !

Comment: with [my answer, to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13153847/720508) i think you should be able to solve this, if not then please show your controller action that renders the _view.php_ file

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not passing a `$data` variable to `_comment.php`, you're only passing a `$comments` variable when you call `renderPartial()`.

Files that take a `$data` param like your example above are usually designed to be used within a CListView or similar, which you'd need to pass a [data provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) rather than an array (as I assume `$model_comments` is?).

CListView takes a data provider and it converts to a `$data` variable (like you see in your `_comments.php` file) for each record in the data provider.

Assuming `$model_comments` is the 'comments' relations for your model, this should be an array of model objects? If that's the case you don't have to create a new CDataProvider to use with the CListView, you can use [CArrayDataProvide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) to convert that relation array to a data provider which can be used in a CListView. So something like this may work for you;

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($model_comments, array()),
    'itemView'=>'/TblComments/_comment',
));
```

Not tested, and you may need to edit to taste.